# Типы связи в словосочетании

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, как в школе разбирать такие примеры: управление или примыкание?

> Спать в обнимку. Бровки домиком

Можно к наречному сочетанию "в обнимку" задать вопрос "во что"?

Comment: Вид грамматической связи от вопроса не зависит. По вопросу мы определяем обстоятельственное или объектное значение (какой член предложения).

Comment: Грамматическая связь: Это предложное управление В.п. и беспредложное управление Т.п.   Члены предложения:  Спать (как) в обнимку – обстоятельство образа действия. Бровки (какие) домиком – несогласованное определение.

Comment: А какие здесь связи?

Comment: Это управление. Всего три вида связи: согласование, управление (падежом), примыкание (зависимое слово присоединяется к главному только по смыслу, для наречия, деепричастия, инфинитива)
Вот здесь есть примеры https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/vidyi-slovosochetaniy.html

Comment: И там, и там управление? Просто у Валгиной видел, что грамматика-80 подобные примеры рассматривает как падежное примыкание, поэтому вопрос о постановке вопроса к сочетанию и был задан. Падеж ведь нужно здесь увидеть.

Comment: Падежное примыкание - это не школьная тема, не думаю,что вам это нужно.  https://studopedia.su/19_170743_ponyatie-primikaniya-padezhnoe-primikanie-printsipialnie-razlichiya-mezhdu-ponyatiyami-upravleniya-i-primikaniya.html  А падеж, разумеется, определяется по падежному вопросу.  Определить один падеж из шести не так сложно. Вы спрашивали: можно задать вопрос "во что"? А какой еще падежный вопрос можно задать, кроме этого? Да и окончание с предлогом подсказывают падеж.

Comment: А что думаете насчет фразы "сражаться бок о бок", здесь только "как" вижу вопрос.

Comment: Или здесь не имеет это значения, потому что наречные сочетания должны только управляться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Информация по теме** (это надо очень хорошо усвоить или повторить, если уже знаете)

**1. Предлоги**

Предлоги служат для выражения  **падежных** отношений между словами в словосочетании.

Предлоги пишутся всегда раздельно и участвуют в **падежном управлени**и (управление может быть предложным или беспредложным).

Предлоги могут относиться только **к частям речи**, для которых характерно **падежное** управление, а именно к существительным, некоторым местоимениям и числительным, а также к словам, имеющим предметное значение, характерное для существительных

**2. Наречия и наречные выражения**

**Наречные выражения**  с раздельным написанием предлога иначе называются **обстоятельственными существительными**, так как они выражаются падежными формами существительных.

Наречные выражения, как и наречия, имеют **обстоятельственное значение** и отвечают на обстоятельственные вопросы.

Их нужно отличать  от **наречий**, которые тоже имеют обстоятельственное значение и пишутся слитно (наречия – это уже другая часть речи).

**3. Грамматическая связь «управление»**

У нас всего **три вида грамматической связи** (в школьном варианте). Определить управление несложно, это можно сделать даже способом **исключения**: это не согласование и не примыкание.

Примером  **согласования**  является связь  между существительным и **прилагательным**, при этом согласуются грамматические значения рода, числа и падежа, выраженные окончаниями этих слов, например: *в ясном небе.*

**Примыкание** характерно для **трех частей речи**: наречия, деепричастия в роли наречия и инфинитива.

Все остальное – **это управление**. Управление может быть предложным или беспредложным.

Примером  **управления**   служит связь между глаголом и  существительным. В этом случае глагол **задаёт** определённый падеж существительному, что выражается с помощью окончания. Например: *читать книгу* (беспредложное управление винительным падежом, окончание У), *выписать из книги* – предложное управление родительным падежом, окончание И).

**Ответы на вопросы**

1. *Можно к наречному сочетанию  **в обнимку** задать вопрос "во что"?*

Можно, если вы хотите **уточнить падеж**. Один из шести падежей определить несложно: по падежному вопросу, по окончанию, по характерному предлогу.

2. *А какие здесь связи? Спать в обнимку. Бровки домиком.*

Это **управление**: предложное управление В.п. (*спать в обнимку*) и беспредложное управление Т.п. (*бровки домиком*).

3. *А что думаете насчет фразы "сражаться бок о бок", здесь только "как" вижу вопрос.*

***Бок о бок*** – это уже **устойчивое** сочетание с обстоятельственным значением, вопрос «как» – это **не падежный**, а обстоятельственный вопрос для определения **синтаксической роли** **всего** сочетания "бок о бок" в качестве обстоятельства:

***Бок о́ бок*** (разг.) — совсем рядом, вплотную, один подле другого. Стоять бок о бок. **Падежное** управление В.п. присутствует, здесь управление со стороны первого сущ. «бок» в качестве главного, падежный вопрос –  ***обо что***?

4. *Или здесь не имеет это значения, потому что наречные сочетания должны только управляться?*

Да, не имеет значения: наречные сочетания – это обстоятельственные **существительные**, и они должны только управляться.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: Неужели в словосочетании "спать в обнимку" управление? Если, конечно, я верно понял.

Comment: *Спать в обнимку* = *спать обнявшись*. Примыкание (преимущественно слабое) обладает способностью к варьированию зависимых форм: *читать ночами* — *читать по ночам*, *работать дома* — *работать на дому* ([источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Примыкание_(лингвистика))).

Comment: Да, согласен, примыкание, конечно.